# Handling GLTF nodes with multiple vertex formats

Tags: vulkan, gltf

I'm working on implementing support for GLTF 2.0 in a hobby renderer, using Vulkan and C++.
https://www.khronos.org/registry/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html

Initially, I implemented basic support for some test GLTF files. However, after reading the spec closer, I've come across some details that are tough to deal with.

Per the spec, a Node consists of one or more Meshes, and a Mesh consists of one or more Primitives. Within the same Node, each Primitive may use different vertex formats, including:

- Different amount of attributes (ie: Position-only vs Position+Normal)
- Different attribute ordering (ie: Position+Normal vs Normal+Position).
- Accessors that points to arrays of structs vs others that use arrays of elements.

It seems to me that this creates a situation which, in order to make a robust renderer that can handle general GLTF models, one needs to create a bunch of shader permutations the various vertex formats that a Primitive may use. So far, the only idea that has occurred to me on how to avoid an explosion of shader permutations is the following:

- Define a shader with a vertex format that includes all the spec-defined attributes. When parsing a GLTF file, use default values for any missing attributes. When reading the vertex data from the file, if an attribute is present but with a different data type, convert that data to the expected type (ie: promote short to ints). Reorder the attributes to what the shader expects. Additionally, have a few other specialized shaders for when some well known vertex formats are detected (ie: if format is Position+Normal+Coord0, use shader Foo).

I tried a variation on the above, and loading models was very slow. Also, seems like a brittle way to approach this.

***What is another way that I can mitigate the need to, potentially, make alot of pipeline changes for a single node? and/or needing to define many shaders for all the different situations?***

Comment: Broadly speaking, making an "everything renderer" is not a fun path. Vulkan as an API is at its best when you can impose some basic limitations on the stuff you're doing, and the more limits you impose, the more efficient you can make everything. If you're determined to find a way to blast *anything* onto the screen that some glTF file gives you, then you're going to have to accept some consequences from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each primitive is intended to be a separate draw call, likely with a separate shader program.

Notice that the primitive differs by more than just vertex attributes.  The primitive includes its own material reference, so it could be a completely separate material from other primitives owned by the same mesh.

Primitives exist to offer a mechanism to include multiple materials in a single mesh, but they require separate draw calls and separate shaders to implement.  This is talked about in the [Meshes Overview section](https://www.khronos.org/registry/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#meshes).